# How to POST logical type decimal values for Avro records to Confluent Rest Proxy?

Tags: postman, avro, kafka-rest, confluent-rest-proxy

We are using the Confluent Rest Proxy to communicate with Kafka and need to test a variety of data. We are using the Rest Proxy to allow a vendor to communicate with our Kafka system.

One of our fields in the Avro schema has a logical type of decimal. To keep this simple, let's assume the schema shown here:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "fieldName",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "amount",
      "type": {
        "logicalType": "decimal",
        "precision": 16,
        "scale": 2,
        "type": "bytes"
      }
    }
  ],
  "name": "Sample",
  "namespace": "com.test.sample",
  "type": "record"
}
```

It's easy enough to write to the topic via a Java producer, using Avro Tools to produce the appropriate class files. But when attempting to use the Rest Proxy, we have to pass values such as this:

```
{"value_schema_id":132,"records": [{"value":{"fieldName":"Field Name","amount":"\u0001ã"}}]}
```

This was copied from a record created via the Java producer and then downloaded from the topic. But in the `amount` field, we'd like to be able to pass a value such as `123.45`. We're using Postman for the most part to send data. Is there a way to do this with a logical decimal field and *without* having to create and serialize the data first to see the representation such as `\u0001ã`?

Comment: So, your Java client cannot directly publish to Kafka? If so, you could write an HTTP client in Java instead of using Postman to simulate the messages. If you really want to use Postman, then wrap that message generator in a Java HTTP server that forwards the (converted) request to the REST Proxy

Comment: Our use case requires the use of Rest Proxy and our testers aren't writing code. We have a vendor that will be writing to the system. The Java client is just for our internal testing. We could also test using Curl, but we'd have the same problem. It seems Rest Proxy can't be used for any of the more complex types - such as decimal - and everything I've seen says to write an application. This seems to make the Rest Proxy not particularly useful. I've updated the question to include the info about vendor interaction.

Comment: We have - for now, anyway - abandoned trying to use ```decimal``` with REST Proxy and instead are using ```string```.